# How to use NotifyBuilder with Spring ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, apache-camel

simple question I guess but I cannot find an answer yet.

Pretty new to camel, I'm trying to use 'best practices' and therefore I 
 "boot up the CamelContext in Spring and write routing rules in Java DSL RouteBuilders".

So I have:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
```

I'm now trying to use NotifyBuilder:

```
 NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder().whenDone(1).create();
```

NotifyBuilder need the context in parameters but don't accept an 'Application context' or a cast().
I tryied to put getContext() as parameter but then my boolean:

```
boolean done = notify.matches(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

is always false...

So how can I use NotifyBuilder with Spring defining the context please?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard spring api to get the camel context using its getBean api

Something a long the lines of

```
CamelContext camel = context.getBean("idOfCamelContext", CamelContext.class);
```

eg check the api on `ApplicationContext`

The id of the bean is the id attribute you set in the xml file if you use `<camelContext>`

```
<camelContext id="idOfCamelContext" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the `NotifyBuilder` instance *before* the body is sent:

```
CamelContext camelContext = ...
ProducerTemplate template = ...

NotifyBuilder notifyBefore = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
            .from("direct:start").whenDone(1)
            .create();

template.sendBody("direct:start", "Wow!!!!");

NotifyBuilder notifyAfter = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
            .from("direct:start").whenDone(1)
            .create();

LOG.info("done (before) = {}", notifyBefore.matches(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
LOG.info("done (after)  = {}", notifyAfter.matches(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

This prints:

```
INFO  done (before) = true
INFO  done (after)  = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for responses guys. I'm ashamed of asking for more, but I am obviously missing something.

I'm running my application with

```
camel:run
```

as maven goals. If I get it right, it automaticly launch camel context from my "META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml" file.

So the line:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
```

was useless as the program never entered in the main.
After getting that, I tried to:

-Apply Claus answer getting my ApplicationContext context and then setting the regular CamelContext with

```
CamelContext camel = context.getBean("idOfCamelContext", CamelContext.class);
```

in an other bean file or route. When I do that, the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is constantly refreshing, over and over and nothing is happening after.

-Change my mvn goals with

```
compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.blabla.MyMain
```

and then setting in my main method applicationContext and camelContext with the id trick.
But the route is launched BEFORE the camelContext being set, and I still can't use notifyBuilder(camelContext) as it is null at that time. So I can't test Peter's answer right now.

I'm sorry if that is dumb question :-). I can make it work with full JavaDSL but I really don't get how Spring is operating. (Non really related but I don't even manage to control how to start and stop context with Spring when in pure JavaDSL we could simply do):

```
context.start()
thread.sleep(10000)
context.stop()
```

Thanks again for your time.